# How to make TextField align right (trailing)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to have the value of a **TextField** displayed with trailing alignment.

As you can see the value *34.3* is display with leading alignment.

I am sure I am missing something obvious but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

```
@State private var endwert = 34.3

var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    return formatter
}

...

HStack {

  Text("Endwert")
    .frame(width: nil, height: nil, alignment: .topTrailing)
    .background(Color .green)

  Spacer()

  TextField($endwert, formatter: numberFormatter)
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .frame(width: nil, height: nil, alignment: .trailing)

  Text("m2")
}
```

[image: wich looks like this]

Comment: Try replacing the arguments of the TextField with the string literal “34.3”. The number formatter looks good BUT if white space is being added after the number somehow, then the trailing alignment in your example would be correct. Simply put. There should be no white space after your number (the blank space with the yellow background)

Comment: I was coming from that. Without the numberformatter the result was the same. I was actually hoping with using the numberformater swiftui decides it’s a number and align trailing. But that was not the case.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Add `.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)` to your TextField:

```
TextField($endwert, formatter: numberFormatter)
  .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
  ...
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Works for SecureFields as well.

Comment: The only problem with `.trailing` is that selecting that TextField with content inside automatically places the cursor on the far left instead of the right side.